# R str_replace / remove access zeros in string after the decimal seperator, (zero following dot[1-9]) gesub, regex, regular expression

Tags: r, regex, str-replace, gsub, remove-if

I have vector of strings containing numbers. Within these strings, I would like to remove all access zeros behind the decimal separator.  So I tried `mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., ".00", "")))`.

This works for the first number in my vector:
 `v <- c("bla 500.00", "bla 1.20", "bla 1.10", "bla 2.34")`.

For the rest I would not like to hard code `mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., ".10", ".1")))%>%mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., ".20", ".2")))%>% ...`, but use some kind of smart regex, which automatically does the job. So, removing every zero which is behind ".non-zero-integer" (dot non-zero-integer), while keeping the ".non-zero-integer" the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to find:

```
\b(\d+)(?:\.0+|(\.\d+?))0*\b
```

And replace with `\1\2`. See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/k8Yxhn/1)

---

- `\b` - Word-boundary;
- `(\d+)` - Capture trailing digits upto;
- `(?:` - Open a non-capture group;

  - `\.0+` - 1+ zero's;
  - `|` - Or;
  - `(\.\d+?)` - A nested 2nd capture group to match a dot followed by a digit and 0+ (lazy) digits;
  - `)` - Close non-capture group;
- `0*` - 0+ (greedy) digits;
- `\b` - Trailing word-boundary.

---

```
library(stringr)
v <- c("bla 500.00", "bla 1.20", "bla 1.10", "bla 2.34", "bla 2.340003", "bla 1.032", "bla 1.10 bla 2.00")
v <- str_replace_all(v, "\\b(\\d+)(?:\\.0+|(\\.\\d+?))0*\\b", "\\1\\2")
v
```

Prints: `"bla 500", "bla 1.2", "bla 1.1", "bla 2.34", "bla 2.340003", "bla 1.032", "bla 1.1 bla 2"`

Answer (score 2):

How about this base R solution:

```r
v <- c("bla 500.00", "bla 1.20", "bla 1.10", "bla 2.34")
v <- gsub("(.*[\\.1-9])0*$", "\\1", v)
v <- gsub("\\.$", "", v)
v
#> [1] "bla 500"  "bla 1.2"  "bla 1.1"  "bla 2.34"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>
The first `gsub()` function removes trailing zeros and the second `gsub()` removes the period if it is at the end of the number, so it changes `500.` into `500`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Note that `mutate_all` has been [superseded](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html) by `mutate(across())` (see the [docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html)).

```r
v <- c("bla 500.00", "bla 1.20", "bla 1.10", "bla 2.34")
dat  <- data.frame(v = v)

dat  |>
    mutate(
        across(v, \(x) stringr::str_replace(x, "\\.\\d{2}", ""))
    )

#         v
# 1 bla 500
# 2   bla 1
# 3   bla 1
# 4   bla 2
```

**Base R**

```
gsub("\\.\\d{2}", "", dat$v)
# "bla 500" "bla 1"   "bla 1"   "bla 2"
```